# Is it possible to use external exe with ServiceInstall wix element?

Tags: .net-core, wix

My service is a .net core Dll so I need to register it with SCM (Service Control manager" as "C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe  {path to my dll}"

Is it possible to use external exe with ServiceInstall wix element?

Comment: Why do you need an external EXE when WiX provides built-in elements to install the service? It is much the point to have a standard solution for such things.

Comment: Because one way to host a .net core service is to run.. "dotnet.exe service.dll".  https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/10465

Answer (score 0):

***WiX Service Install Samples***: Whilst waiting for you to update your question with more details, I will just lob you a couple of links to good and simple samples of installing services with WiX:

- [Rainer Stropek's Windows Service WiX Sample](https://github.com/rstropek/Samples/tree/master/WiXSamples/WindowsService)
- [Helge Klein full installer sample for WiX](https://helgeklein.com/blog/2014/09/real-world-example-wix-msi-application-installer/) (search for **`ServiceInstall`**)
- [Chris Painter's IsWiX service installation sample](https://github.com/iswix-llc/iswix-tutorials/tree/master/windows-service)